# Git Lab: How to get issues by user id without authentication

Tags: node.js, git, api, gitlab

Following the [GitLab Api Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/issues.html) i can't found a solution to my problem.

Need to get every open issue and closed issues from up to 2 days ago using GitLab api, preferably grouping them by the user whom has the issue assigned.

The solution right now its doing a request to `bring all the groups` from the gitlab, and do a request for each group to bring its issues closed and open, select only the closed ones from 2 days ago, then get all the users from gitlab and start comparing who has assigned which issue ***(most urgent change its that "getting every single one closed issue" since request can take a lot)***.

GitLab api appears to be able to bring issues created or asignated to the authenticated user, but still doesnt bring issues created by other users ***(even when i'm using an admin key to authenticate the api requests)***

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that it is not possible to request all issues at once, but it is possible to request issues on behalf of other users.

For this there is the `sudo` parameter. This parameter you can use to impersonate any user as long you are a admin.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/README.html#sudo